# Facing some problem in 2D array to add each row-wise elements in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, addition

In c++, I wrote a code for 2d array to add each row-wise elements. But I don't understand why I got sum=3 in row 5 and 6 where I would get the sum = 2 instead of 3.but in my code others row gave the correct results. I don't know where is the problem?

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(){
    
    int a[8][4]={{1,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0}};
    
       for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
           }
    
       cout<<endl<<endl;
    
    
       int a_row[4]={0};
    
    
       cout<<endl;
    
       for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {
    
    
            a_row[i]=a_row[i]+a[i][j];
    
    
    
           }
           cout<<"Row"<<i+1<<":  "<<a_row[i]<<endl;
    
    
    
    
       }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

and the output i got-[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look how big `a_row` is

```
int a_row[4]={0};
```

Now look how big `i` is

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
```

Now look how you use `a_row` and `i`

```
a_row[i]=a_row[i]+a[i][j];
```

See the problem?

Actually there's no need to `a_row` to be an array at all. A simple `int` variable would work just as well. You don't always have to use an array just because you have a loop.